# Render two components from a switch statement react

Tags: reactjs

**GOAL:** Return two components in a switch statement. Specifically, how can I render both my  `LinkButtonTypes` & `LinkList` component?

Here is my switch statement:

```js
 const switchComponent = ({ selectedSidebar }) => {
    let component;
    switch (selectedSidebar) {
      // main dashboard components
      case "dashboard":
        component = <LinkButtonTypes setLinkType={setLinkType} /> && (
          <LinkList/>
        );
        break;
      // render editor components
      case "skins":
        component = <SkinsEditor />;
        break;

      default:
        console.log("Unknwon switch component");
    }
    return component;
  };
```

Here is where I render the components:

```js
<div className="dash__middle">
        {switchComponent({ selectedSidebar })}

      </div>
```

Currently, the switch statement only renders my `LinkButtonTypes` component.

How can I render both my  `LinkButtonTypes` & `LinkList` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Fragment`, like this:

```js
const switchComponent = ({ selectedSidebar }) => {
    let component;
    switch (selectedSidebar) {
      // main dashboard components
      case "dashboard":
        component = (
            <React.Fragment>
                <LinkButtonTypes setLinkType={setLinkType} />
                <LinkList/>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
        break;
      // render editor components
      case "skins":
        component = <SkinsEditor />;
        break;

      default:
        console.log("Unknwon switch component");
    }
    return component;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fragment issue, you should call `switchComponent` as a *component*, not as an ordinary function. Capitalize it (as functional components should be), then do:

```
<div className="dash__middle">
  <SwitchComponent {...{ selectedSidebar }} />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why?

Comment: Using JSX syntax to render components is the proper React way of doing things. Avoiding the JSX can *work* for a while, but it's easy for it to bite you later, like if you try to add in something which is only permitted inside a component (like a hook).